# The effect of orientation on object segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am trying to detect potatoes using deep learning and sliding window approach to locate the potatoes. Since the CNN is not affected by orientation of the object that has been used to train the model, I don't see any problem in training the model but when it comes to detection there is huge issue. You see, the potatoes are more or less like cucumbers. And since I'm using sliding window technique, it is not possible to fit a potato which is in different orientation. For reference see the below image. What should I do for the detection part of the segmentation process?[image]

Comment: Are you running the detection on the image with different scales? Try running one detection on the original scale and one on the down-sampled image. If that works use image pyramids and for each scale your sliding window detection.

Comment: @AmitayNachmani No, I am not running different scale! Also, I am using dlilb and I think it does implement image pyramid. It just how tightly these potatoes are packed is what makes them a pain in the ass!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [neural network](https://github.com/ivan-alles/localizer) is an example of how to handle object rotation. It uses a dataset where both object positions and orientations are labeled. Additionally, it used data augmentation with rotations. The rotation angle (more precisely, its sine and cosine) is added to the model output and the loss function.

So, the model detects the objects regardless of their orientation and also predicts their angles.

If you do not need to predict the angle, you can add rotated objects in the dataset and data augmentation without learning the angle. This will make the model rotationally invariant.